# Cannot be used for full-text search because it is nondeterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a view using 3 tables and converted all the columns to `nvarchar` using convert function.

One of the column was `float` which is also converted to `nvarchar`. When I try to include this column in full text index I get an error:

> cannot be used for full-text search because it is nondeterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column. Error 9928

This column is not a computed column.

Please help.

Regards
Ravikiran S

Comment: I doubt what you say is totally true. You must be including a non-deterministic column somehow. Anyway, this question cannot be answered without seeing the table definition.

Comment: From the Property of the column I can see that property-- Computed Column Specification has (Formula) blank and Is Persisted as  No. I can give complete details of my table. If you want to know some specific property please let me know, I would provide the details on that.